# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server /etc/fstab missing, system still works

Tags: server, 20.04, fstab

I'm honestly so confused how this is even possible.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server on a computer recently and have been getting it set up.  I'm just finishing setting up the backup scripts when I go to add the drive to `/etc/fstab` and to my surprise the file is completely missing.

Aside from questions of how did this happen with a fresh install, how is my system working?  I've rebooted several times since I installed and it never seemed to run into any issues missing the fstab.  It's even mounting the swap partition correctly.  Is there some other mechanism it's using that I don't know about?

My setup:

```
(0) $ lsblk -f
NAME    FSTYPE            LABEL      UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                      
├─sda1  ext4                         e9e5240c-c1fb-4200-a53a-c292262b4c1f                
├─sda2  ext4                         08cd4f9d-c984-4196-a1ba-70abbeba94d1  824.8G     2% /
└─sda3  swap                         95315f9e-6b9e-44c4-ae8e-a123b04714f4                [SWAP]             
sdc                                                                                      
└─sdc1  ext3              Back Ups   152942fd-96f2-4164-8ec1-cbfa2ef55b0e  741.4G    14% /mnt/backup
```

The `/mnt/backup` I added manually.  `/` and `[SWAP]` were automatically mounted somehow.

Comment: Use `/etc/mtab` (the operating system's idea of what's mounted) to regenerate `/etc/fstab` **before** you reboot.

Comment: I appreciate that advice, but what's weird is that I already have rebooted multiple times.  Can anyone explain why this hasn't failed catastrophically yet?

Comment: How did you determine the file was missing?

Comment: Also, [this answer may help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451289). I guess systemd handles the mounting and uses fstab as a reference. Still, not something I would recommend without further information.

Comment: @mchid I typed `sudo emacs /etc/fstab` and it said the file didn't exist.  I assumed it was a typo so I tried opening the directory and I couldn't find it.  To sanity check that it wasn't an emacs error, I typed, `ls /etc | grep fstab` and it came back blank.

Comment: @mchid It looks like that is what's happening but because it's on a different stack exchange I can't call this a duplicate of that.  Would you like to post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: @Thomas Maybe if I look into this more. I don't really understand it yet so I wouldn't feel comfortable posting it as an answer as of now. I mean, I understand the concept but I'd have to read up a bit.

Comment: Please be precise with details; Ubuntu Core 20 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS are different server products; the 20 being capable of using *snap* packages only; has a 10 year supported life & boots quickly; 20.04 is a more complex product that can use *deb* and *snap* packages but has a shorter life (which can be extended via ESM use to match 20). You mention both; 20 in question & 20.04 in tags - but they are different Ubuntu server products.  Please be precise with details & don't use contradictory detail  (20 is based on 20.04 yes, but is a *smaller* product intended for appliance/device/cloud use)